# CRM 2011 - Adding a new Item via the Subgrid results in "An Error Has Occured"-error. Happens only on Windows 8 with IE 10

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, subgrid

We are for the moment on ROLLUP 11 with CRM 2011 and we're encountering a weird problem with the CRM when using Windows 8 and IE 10.  We've added the CRM URL in the "Comptability Settings", otherwise the lookups don't work...

When you click on a subgrid in an entity (all entities gave an error) and you click on "Add New ..." and then you create your item.  Afterwards you click on "Save" or "Save & Close" then the screen won't close (in case of "Save & Close") and an "Error"-message will be shown on the page where the subgrid resides. (Same happens on "Save")

It's a typical "An Error Has Occured"-error, but with the "Download LogFile"-button greyed out.  When you click on "OK" in the "Error"-message, then you are able to close the page of the new Item and it is also added to the subgrid. I think, it's when you Refresh the subgrid (by adding the item), the error happens.

I tried to use developer tools, to see what could go wrong, but it didn't even show me the error...

Everything works as it should on my Windows 7 with IE 10. I was able to reproduce the error on several PC's with windows 8 and IE 10.

Comment: Sounds like a server side error. Have you turned on tracing on the server and check what the logs spit out? (FYI - Easiest way to enable tracing is using the Diagnostics Tool)

Comment: The problem is gone with the installation of Rollup 14! But now I need to change al the javascript :)